# Is there a reason my Powershell script is now returning null-value expression errors?

Tags: powershell, indexing, html-parsing

As the title suggests, I have a script that I've been running daily to parse tables from a web page and export those to a csv. A few days ago though, I realized the script has been returning the following errors:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\Users\Luke\DailyStats\NHLStats.ps1:16 char:1
+ $headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Cannot index into a null array. At C:\Users\Luke\DailyStats\NHLStats.ps1:23 char:14
+ $headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray   Cannot index into a null array. At C:\Users\Luke\DailyStats\NHLStats.ps1:23 char:33
+ $headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

I don't get why all of a sudden it randomly stopped working. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

My script:

```
$url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020.html"

#getting the data
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $url

#grab the third table
$table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -skip 2 | Select -First 1


#get the rows of the Team Statistics table
$rows = $table.rows

#get table headers
$headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText
#$headers = $headers | % { if ($_ -eq "GF") { "GFPG" }  else { $_ }}

#count the number of rows
$NumOfRows = $rows | Measure-Object

#Manually injecting TEAM header and replace any headers you want to change
$headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])

#enumerate the remaining rows (we need to skip the header row) and create a custom object
$allData = @{}
$out = for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
 #define an empty hashtable
 $objHash=[ordered]@{}
 #getting the child rows
 $rowdata = $rows.item($i).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText 
 for ($j=0;$j -lt $headers.count;$j++) {
    #add each row of data to the hash table using the correlated table header value
    $objHash[$headers[$j]] = $rowdata[$j]        
  }

  #turn the hashtable into a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$objHash
  $allData.Add($i, $objHash)
}

$out | Select TEAM,AvAge,GP,W,L,OL,PTS,PTS%,GF,GA,SOW,SOL,SRS,SOS,TG/G,EVGF,EVGA,PP,PPO,PP%,PPA,PPOA,PK%,SH,SHA,PIM/G,oPIM/G,S,S%,SA,SV%,SO -SkipLast 1 | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Luke\DailyStats\$((Get-Date).ToString("'NHL Stats' yyyy-MM-dd")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It seems that the input from your URL has changed and you're not getting the same data rendering `$rows` NULL. Check the values of `$table` and `$table.rows`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `$table` variable is returning `null`. When running that `|select -skip 2 | select -first 1`, it isn't returning any data to the `$table` variable.

This seems to be related to the **-skip 2** selection.
When running just the portion of the `$table = $data.ParsedHtml...`
It only returns two objects.

So possibly you need to update your selection to properly retrieve the table that you want?

I am only seeing the 'standings EAS' and 'standings WES' tables being pulled.

Comment: Interesting, so if I wanted to grab the Team Statistics table, would it be as simple as changing the number to indicate that table?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it appears the Team Statistics table isn't being returned by the getElementsByTagName function. Looking at the page now to see if I can figure out why that is

Comment: Ultimately it looks like that page renders differently in the browser than in Powershell. Specifically, when looking at the HTML in Powershell, there's a blank section underneath the 'Team Statistics' title where a table should go.

Comment: I noticed that too. Is that a site design issue then?

Comment: It's definitely a site design issue, but I'm sure if you parsed the HTML out via a different source you would likely get an actually workable table.
I'm not sure if Powershell has this ability, currently looking at the -UserAgent flag of Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: Well, seems like even with a variety of user agent strings, it's still not loading.
Browsing the page and stopping it from loading right when elements start to load leads to a similar page load to Powershell's HTML.
So it seems like there's possibly some javascript loading additional tables after the initial render of the page.
Not sure how to get around that without automating a whole interactive browser window...